# React Async Rendering Time-Slicing And Suspense

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I was wondering if the implementations which were referred here [react](https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/03/27/update-on-async-rendering.html) are ready for the developers and if yes where can i find them?

In the react's doc section doesnt refer to any async rendering examples except for Suspense [Suspense](https://reactjs.org/docs/code-splitting.html#suspense).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All the new lifecycle hooks mentioned are already available in the latest versions of react.

Suspense is useful to show some loader-like content while actual component is imported lazyly using `React.lazy`
[ refer : https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactsuspense ]

<s>The rendering engine would change in future releases and the new async renderer is expected to feature in React 17.0 as mentioned in the docs.</s> There would not be much changes as far as development is concerned other than deprecation of the mentioned lifeCycle hooks

Edit:

The async renderer (or 'concurrent mode', as I think the React team are calling it) is intended to be released in a 16.x minor release, according to the roadmap. It's not a breaking change to the API, so it wouldn't need to go into a major release.

Comment: One minor correction - the async renderer (or 'concurrent mode', as I think the React team are calling it) is intended to be released in a 16.x minor release, [according to the roadmap](https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/11/27/react-16-roadmap.html#react-16x-q2-2019-the-one-with-concurrent-mode). It's not a breaking change to the API, so it wouldn't need to go into a major release.